# Loading and Smoothness of a TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

I have two questions regarding a UITableView:

1. **How do implement an activity indicator in a tableview while the data that will populate the table is loading?**
2. While scrolling through data that is already loaded in the tableview, the labels and images seem "jumpy" as it is trying to fill up the cell's labels and image view with the information. **How do I fix this so as I am scrolling the labels and images are "jumpy" as they try to fit in the cell?**

*Note: to understand what I am trying to convey, think about an app like Instagram and how they show an activity indicator while peoples post load and how as you scroll down through posts all of the cells are not jumpy.*

Comment: for number 2: you will need to show some picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use something like SDWebImage to cache the images. Labels don't really take a lot of time, but images do. If you are not caching, every time you scroll, it loads the image again and again. For activity indicator, I suggest you use a completion handler.

What I mean by that is it would let you know that the upload is complete, so you can start the activity indicator as soon as you click upload and stop it when you reach the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

> How do implement an activity indicator in a tableview while the data that will populate the table is loading?

There are several approaches you can take. You can place a view with an activity indicator on top of the table -- in a higher layer, so that it stays in place even if the table scrolls. Or you can populate the table with placeholder images until the actual images are available, at which point you can reload any cells that are currently being displayed. Or you can hide the table entirely and just show the activity indicator until the table is ready. Think about what you want the user experience to be.

> How do I fix this so as I am scrolling the labels and images are [not] "jumpy" as they try to fit in the cell?

First, figure out what's slowing things down. Profiling can help here, but so can simple experimentation. Are you loading the images from the network? If yes, does the table perform better if the images are already stored on the device? Does caching the images in memory help? How about changing the size of the images? Does adding placeholder images instead of waiting for the image to be available help? It's a good bet that a table that uses images that aren't larger than necessary and caches them in memory will scroll a lot more smoothly than one that's loading big images over the network synchronously. We don't know what your code is doing, so you'll have to figure it out for yourself, but in general the guideline is **do less work** for each cell.